# Angular2: View is not updating from Socket.io event

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I was simply trying to update my view when I receive an socket event.
My code in the component is something like below:

```
constructor(private _zone: NgZone){
    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    this.socket.on('someEvent', function(data) {
        this._zone.run(() => {
            this.dataItem = data.item;
            console.log(this.dataItem);
        });
    });
}
```

when I run this browser console show some errors:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
```

btw, my socket event are working properly in index.html

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `function ()` because this way `this` doesn't point to the current class instance anymore. Use arrow functions instead:

```
this.socket.on('someEvent', (data) => {
```